# Fedora session / process startup issues

Tags: fedora, startup, lxde

I've installed fedora 16 with lxde(xfce) desktop. My problem is that when I login into the system, it gives me redundant app startup, for instance it launches Installation manager, also I've noticed quite a few httpd processes. Looks really strange to me. Any suggestions guys ?

```
[midnight@localhost ~]$ ps aux | grep httpd
root       985  0.0  0.3 437472  9964 ?        Ss   18:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache     988  0.0  0.4 441816 12112 ?        S    18:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache     989  0.0  0.2 437472  6112 ?        S    18:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache     990  0.0  0.2 437472  5364 ?        S    18:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache     991  0.0  0.2 437472  5364 ?        S    18:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache     992  0.0  0.2 437472  5364 ?        S    18:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache     993  0.0  0.2 437472  5364 ?        S    18:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache     994  0.0  0.2 437472  5364 ?        S    18:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache     995  0.0  0.2 437472  5364 ?        S    18:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
```

Comment: Do you have anything funny in your `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart/` or `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` files?

Comment: nope,I even don't have such directories, instead I found /etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf,~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/ and their conf-files seem legit.

Comment: Having several `httpd` threads is normal, this is the way Apache works. Is the installation manager started when you log in, or when the system boots? Does it also show up on other user accounts?

Comment: Why install an already unsupported version of Fedora?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to convince the xfce session manager to get out of my way, even by tinkering directly with config files. So I now run `rm -r ~/.cache/sessions/x*` before starting xfce. This effectively disables session management and leaves autostart working correctly. You can run this code by including these lines in ~/.xinitrc:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/sessions/x*
exec ck-launch-session startxfce4
```

or you can boot to runlevel 3 and execute:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/sessions/x*
startx
```

If you need to be able to select a different desktop manager at startup, there are probably a few more steps to work out.